# "Erasing" line HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm making a website and having a very problem with one effect. There's a line through all width of browser window. It's fixed (position: fixed). And there's a small area above it. The point of effect is that some content should be "erased" after contacting to that line. So the area above it shows not all blocks but specificated by me. For example, there's yellow block with paddings etc. It also has a small green block with text or image. So above that line, it should be only yellow block without green. I've tried solving this problem using relative positioning and z-indexes. But i can't imagine how can i get that because there's always some "layers", not just one picture as it is in the example. If it was only one block it is easy i think. 
I made a simple example to show you. Please take a look.
And here's a picture to provide more understanding. Imagine that it's all your window and when you scroll down/top blue blocks disappeares/appeares. Only blue blocks. [Picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnkvH.png)

```css
    body{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    }
    .main{
    background-color:#FF6600; 
    padding:200px 0px 0px;
    }
    .fix{
    position:fixed;
    background-color:#FF6600; 
    border-bottom:2px solid black;
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index: 2;
    }
    .container{
    padding: 50px;
    background-color: yellow;
    }
    .block{
    background-color: green;
    }
    .big_pic{
    z-index:2;
    position:relative
    }
    .absolute{
    position:absolute;
    top: 70%;
    z-index: 1;
    }
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="fix">
    </div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent non est sit amet tellus blandit cursus at tincidunt ex. Etiam arcu ante, cursus sed lectus eu, vehicula maximus quam. Nam vel quam porta, pretium leo vel, tristique velit. Quisque ut arcu sit amet quam imperdiet rutrum. Ut volutpat pharetra felis, ac dictum urna blandit ac. Suspendisse facilisis ullamcorper molestie.
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent non est sit amet tellus blandit cursus at tincidunt ex. Etiam arcu ante, cursus sed lectus eu, vehicula maximus quam. Nam vel quam porta, pretium leo vel, tristique velit. Quisque ut arcu sit amet quam imperdiet rutrum. Ut volutpat pharetra felis, ac dictum urna blandit ac. Suspendisse facilisis ullamcorper molestie.</p>    

    <div class="container"> 
    <div class="block">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent non est sit amet tellus blandit cursus at tincidunt ex. Etiam arcu ante, cursus sed lectus eu, vehicula maximus quam. Nam vel quam porta, pretium leo vel, tristique velit. Quisque ut arcu sit amet quam imperdiet rutrum. Ut volutpat pharetra felis, ac dictum urna blandit ac. Suspendisse facilisis ullamcorper molestie. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent non est sit amet tellus blandit cursus at tincidunt ex. Etiam arcu ante, cursus sed lectus eu, vehicula maximus quam. Nam vel quam porta, pretium leo vel, tristique velit. Quisque ut arcu sit amet quam imperdiet rutrum. Ut volutpat pharetra felis, ac dictum urna blandit ac. Suspendisse facilisis ullamcorper molestie.</p>    
    </div>
    </div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent non est sit amet tellus blandit cursus at tincidunt ex. Etiam arcu ante, cursus sed lectus eu, vehicula maximus quam. Nam vel quam porta, pretium leo vel, tristique velit. Quisque ut arcu sit amet quam imperdiet rutrum. Ut volutpat pharetra felis, ac dictum urna blandit ac. Suspendisse facilisis ullamcorper molestie. Nam facilisis elit eu neque sodales fringilla. Morbi laoreet, ex sit amet sagittis congue, risus lorem tempor eros, pulvinar semper sem nunc non erat. Phasellus posuere metus lacus, sit am et sollicitudin purus pulvinar et. Curabitur diam arcu, viverra a magna at, faucibus imperdiet eros. Quisque eros metus, posuere in bibendum eget, mattis eget nisl.et sollicitudin purus pulvinar et. Curabitur diam arcu, viverra a magna at, faucibus imperdiet eros. Quisque eros metus, posuere in bibendum eget, mattis eget nisl.
    <img class="big_pic" src="http://katyaburg.ru/sites/default/files/pictures/krasota_prirody/krasivye_cvety_rozy_kartinki_foto_05.jpg">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent non est sit amet tellus blandit cursus at tincidunt ex. Etiam arcu ante, cursus sed lectus eu, vehicula maximus quam. Nam vel quam porta, pretium leo vel, tristique velit. Quisque ut arcu sit amet quam imperdiet rutrum. Ut volutpat pharetra felis, ac dictum urna blandit ac. Suspendisse facilisis ullamcorper molestie. Nam facilisis elit eu neque sodales fringilla. Morbi laoreet, ex sit amet sagittis congue, risus lorem tempor eros, pulvinar semper sem nunc non erat. Phasellus posuere metus lacus, sit am et sollicitudin purus pulvinar et. Curabitur diam arcu, viverra a magna at, faucibus imperdiet eros. Quisque eros metus, posuere in bibendum eget, mattis eget nisl. et sollicitudin purus pulvinar et. Curabitur diam arcu, viverra a magna at, faucibus imperdiet eros. Quisque eros metus, posuere in bibendum eget, mattis eget nisl.

    Nullam dui libero, gravida id dui ac, pellentesque gravida justo. Quisque id dolor non nunc scelerisque varius a malesuada felis. Duis aliquam malesuada tortor, quis laoreet lacus vestibulum ut. Sed a vestibulum nunc, in maximus magna. Donec vel ante in nisi volutpat venenatis quis sit amet purus. Nunc eget posuere tortor. Donec in mi lectus. Mauris iaculis aliquet orci, at condimentum ligula bibendum et. Cras egestas metus a pellentesque malesuada. Etiam et imperdiet arcu, nec gravida massa. Sed maximus, lorem a dignissim faucibus, lorem neque laoreet elit, ut scelerisque augue ex et odio. Suspendisse ut pretium magna, sed elementum neque. Donec efficitur lectus vitae erat gravida fringilla et vel ante. Sed consectetur, odio vel venenatis mattis, nisl felis dapibus quam, eget ultrices augue nisi quis sapien.
</div>
```

Comment: Make a snippet please

Comment: Have a look at jQuery docs for `offset`, `position` and `detach` http://api.jquery.com. You need to listen to `scroll` (`$(window).on('scroll', function(){…})`) and compare the bottom edge of the fixed div with the bottom edge of the element you want to remove. When the green element's position is less than the fixed element's, you `detach` your green element and do whatever it is you need to do with it.

Comment: BTW, before positing questions you should try something on your own and describe what you tried. So far you mention no attempt at doing this yourself.

Comment: Yeah, of course. I'll edit my question above. I can add that i've tried solving this problem using relative positioning and z-indexes. But i can't imagine how can i get that because there's always some "layers", not just one picture as it is in the example. If it was only one block it is easy i think.

Comment: And i'll take a look at those methods of jQuery, thank you.

Comment: I think i haven't described correctly my task. I don't need to remove that content from DOM. It's only visual effect and as all the text in example code, green text should be under fixed block too but not yellow block. And that will be an effect of erasing text.

Comment: Post a drawing please

Comment: Added a picture

Comment: OK, I think what you are after is generally called "sticking an element" on scroll. Try a search on Google or SO for that?

Answer (score 0):

if i understand u correct u need to remove border from `.fix` class

```css
html, body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.main{
background-color:#FF6600; 
padding:200px 0px 0px;
}
img{
  max-width: 100%;
}
.fix{
position:fixed;
background-color:#FF6600; 
/*border-bottom:2px solid black;*/
height:150px;
width:100%;
top:0px;
left:0px;
z-index: 10;
}
.container{
padding: 50px;
background-color: yellow;
}
.block{
background-color: green;
}
.big_pic{
z-index:2;
position:relative
}
.absolute{
position:absolute;
top: 70%;
z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<div class="fix">

</div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent non est sit amet tellus blandit cursus at tincidunt ex. Etiam arcu ante, cursus sed lectus eu, vehicula maximus quam. Nam vel quam porta, pretium leo vel, tristique velit. Quisque ut arcu sit amet quam imperdiet rutrum. Ut volutpat pharetra felis, ac dictum urna blandit ac. Suspendisse facilisis ullamcorper molestie.
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent non est sit amet tellus blandit cursus at tincidunt ex. Etiam arcu ante, cursus sed lectus eu, vehicula maximus quam. Nam vel quam porta, pretium leo vel, tristique velit. Quisque ut arcu sit amet quam imperdiet rutrum. Ut volutpat pharetra felis, ac dictum urna blandit ac. Suspendisse facilisis ullamcorper molestie.</p>    

<div class="container"> 
<div class="block">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent non est sit amet tellus blandit cursus at tincidunt ex. Etiam arcu ante, cursus sed lectus eu, vehicula maximus quam. Nam vel quam porta, pretium leo vel, tristique velit. Quisque ut arcu sit amet quam imperdiet rutrum. Ut volutpat pharetra felis, ac dictum urna blandit ac. Suspendisse facilisis ullamcorper molestie. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent non est sit amet tellus blandit cursus at tincidunt ex. Etiam arcu ante, cursus sed lectus eu, vehicula maximus quam. Nam vel quam porta, pretium leo vel, tristique velit. Quisque ut arcu sit amet quam imperdiet rutrum. Ut volutpat pharetra felis, ac dictum urna blandit ac. Suspendisse facilisis ullamcorper molestie.</p>    
</div>
</div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent non est sit amet tellus blandit cursus at tincidunt ex. Etiam arcu ante, cursus sed lectus eu, vehicula maximus quam. Nam vel quam porta, pretium leo vel, tristique velit. Quisque ut arcu sit amet quam imperdiet rutrum. Ut volutpat pharetra felis, ac dictum urna blandit ac. Suspendisse facilisis ullamcorper molestie. Nam facilisis elit eu neque sodales fringilla. Morbi laoreet, ex sit amet sagittis congue, risus lorem tempor eros, pulvinar semper sem nunc non erat. Phasellus posuere metus lacus, sit am et sollicitudin purus pulvinar et. Curabitur diam arcu, viverra a magna at, faucibus imperdiet eros. Quisque eros metus, posuere in bibendum eget, mattis eget nisl.et sollicitudin purus pulvinar et. Curabitur diam arcu, viverra a magna at, faucibus imperdiet eros. Quisque eros metus, posuere in bibendum eget, mattis eget nisl.

<img class="big_pic" src="http://katyaburg.ru/sites/default/files/pictures/krasota_prirody/krasivye_cvety_rozy_kartinki_foto_05.jpg">

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent non est sit amet tellus blandit cursus at tincidunt ex. Etiam arcu ante, cursus sed lectus eu, vehicula maximus quam. Nam vel quam porta, pretium leo vel, tristique velit. Quisque ut arcu sit amet quam imperdiet rutrum. Ut volutpat pharetra felis, ac dictum urna blandit ac. Suspendisse facilisis ullamcorper molestie. Nam facilisis elit eu neque sodales fringilla. Morbi laoreet, ex sit amet sagittis congue, risus lorem tempor eros, pulvinar semper sem nunc non erat. Phasellus posuere metus lacus, sit am et sollicitudin purus pulvinar et. Curabitur diam arcu, viverra a magna at, faucibus imperdiet eros. Quisque eros metus, posuere in bibendum eget, mattis eget nisl. et sollicitudin purus pulvinar et. Curabitur diam arcu, viverra a magna at, faucibus imperdiet eros. Quisque eros metus, posuere in bibendum eget, mattis eget nisl.

Nullam dui libero, gravida id dui ac, pellentesque gravida justo. Quisque id dolor non nunc scelerisque varius a malesuada felis. Duis aliquam malesuada tortor, quis laoreet lacus vestibulum ut. Sed a vestibulum nunc, in maximus magna. Donec vel ante in nisi volutpat venenatis quis sit amet purus. Nunc eget posuere tortor. Donec in mi lectus. Mauris iaculis aliquet orci, at condimentum ligula bibendum et. Cras egestas metus a pellentesque malesuada. Etiam et imperdiet arcu, nec gravida massa. Sed maximus, lorem a dignissim faucibus, lorem neque laoreet elit, ut scelerisque augue ex et odio. Suspendisse ut pretium magna, sed elementum neque. Donec efficitur lectus vitae erat gravida fringilla et vel ante. Sed consectetur, odio vel venenatis mattis, nisl felis dapibus quam, eget ultrices augue nisi quis sapien.

</div>
```

Comment: No, you don't understand me. I need to "erase" green block above the line  so it should be only yellow block (.container) without green one (.block).